# Opening a program and then waiting for it

Tags: wait, fish

Is there a general way to `wait` for an executed process that backgrounds in fish (like `open "foo"`)? As far as I can tell, `$!` (the PID of the last executed child process in bash) is not present in fish, so you can't just [`wait $!`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124106/shell-script-wait-for-background-command).

Comment: What do you mean by `IF_OK_CMD`? What is `open` (i.e. which OS)? I'm confused why you want to `fg` the process when you never put it in the background. By default processes execute in the foreground. Is it possible that `open` is just exiting?

Comment: I'll edit it to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. I suspect what is happening is that `open` is just exiting - it's not being backgrounded, it just finishes opening the file and so exits. If this is OS X, perhaps you want `open -W`?

Comment: `cmd1 && cmd2` in fish is `cmd1; and cmd2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The fish idiom is `cmd1; and cmd2` or `if cmd1; cmd2; end`.

2) You should find that bash and zsh also don't block if you execute `open ARG`. That's because `open` will normally background the program being run then `open` exits. The shell has no idea that `open` has put the "real" program in the background. Another example of that behavior is launching vim in GUI mode via `vim -g`. Add the `-W` flag on macOS or `-w` on Linux to the open command and `-f` to the vim command.

The key here is that `open`, even if it backgrounds, won't return a signal that fish will use to evaluate the `and` operator until something happens to the opened process. So you get the behavior you're looking for.